# Selecting only 10 characters (right) on vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro VBA that allow me for example:

```
Column A:   123456789101112       Column F : 6789101112
```

Only 10 characters in column `F`.  If we have less than 10 characters in column `A` to complete with 0 for example:

```
Column A:  123458    Column F: 0000123458
```

This is the function that allow me to select the number of characters:

```
For i = 1 To table1Rows - 1  
table1(1 + i, 6) = Right(table1(1 + i, 1), 15)
```

But I need to complete the 10 characters if I have less than 10 in column `A`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an Excel formula (e.g. `=TEXT(RIGHT(A2,10),"0000000000")`?

Comment: Was about to same same as @Zack - `=TEXT(RIGHT(A1,10),REPT(0,10))`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: Well, I would argue that your way is clearer, with `REPT`. :)

Comment: @Zack Nah, either way is good.  Yours might even be a millionth of a second faster (doesn't need to translate `0,10`)

Comment: I think that your formula is good but I need to automatize this with a macro VBA. could you please translate this formula on code? thanks

Comment: `Format$(Right$(value, 10), "0000000000")`

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't works:

Comment: For i = 1 To table1Rows - 1


table1(1 + i, 6) = Format$(Right$((table1(1 + i, 1)), 15), "000000000000000")

Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will place the formula in column `F` based on the amount of data in column `A`.
The formula uses `r1c1` notation - `R` on its own means this row, `C1` means column 1.

It's the same as writing `=TEXT(RIGHT(A1,10),REPT(0,10))` and dragging down.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rLastRow As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) 'Based on column A (column #1)

        'Column A Offset by 5 columns is column F.
        .Range(.Cells(1, 6), rLastRow.Offset(, 5)).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=TEXT(RIGHT(RC1,10),REPT(0,10))"

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
For i = 1 To table1Rows - 1
    table1(1 + i, 6) = Format(Right(table1(1 + i, 1), 10), "0000000000")
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

following code will add the remaing zero's to your string:

```
Dim strnbr As String

strnbr = 123

While Len(strnbr) < 10
    strnbr = "0" + strnbr
Wend
```

Comment: thanks, but that allow me just to add 0 if it s less than 10. My need is to have each time 10 characters, and for example if I have 6 characters your code will allow to have just 7 characters on adding 0. in my case I have 6 characters, 5 characters...it s not the same lenth each time. thanks for your help

Comment: the loop will give you 10 characters each time. if you have 5 , it will add 5 time a "0"

Comment: @Wouter he also needs to reduce the number lenght to exactly 10 characters if, for example he has 11 or more